# c# load an image from URL into picturebox

Tags: c#

Im seeking your help again!
I'm new in c#,so please don't be wondering why I'm asking such things. :)

I'm facing a weird issue ritenow. I have this code:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://www.jmorganmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/image4.jpg";
    }
```

The problem is that the image is showing(loading) **only** when I click inside of the picturebox.

Can someone give me an example on how to load the image without clicking in it?

THANKS in advance for any replay!

Comment: why didn't you put that code inside the constructor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the code in your page_load event, not the picturebox1_click event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://www.jmorganmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/image4.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote the code inside `Click` event of picture box. It means when it clicked do the job. you should put `pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://www.jmorganmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/image4.jpg";` whenever you want to set the image.

Answer (score 1):

Simply register a Load EventHandler and set the URL of your picturebox there.